# Filtering a list based on a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net, linq, logic

I need some help with my logic here.

I'm trying to filter a list of objects that I got from multiple calls to an external API. The inputs I got can be for any of the fields of the objects.

My code goes something like this:

```
public ResultData GetData(string request){
  string[] splitRequest = request.Split(' ');

  ResultData resultData = new ResultData();

  foreach(string split in splitRequest){
    //send requests and fill resultData
    //external/api/user/firstname/{input}
    //external/api/user/lastname/{input}
    //external/api/user/username/{input}
    var exampleData = new {
      UserName= "ABC",
      FirstName= "FOO",
      LastName= "BAR"
    }
    resultData.Add(exampleData);
  }
  //There might be doubles, remove those
  resultData = resultData.Distinct();
  //TODO: filter resultData so it's the closest match(es)
}
```

Now what I want is if the request is for instance "FOO BAR" then it returns the user with first name FOO and last name BAR, but if the request was "BAR FOO" it should still return that same user. That same request might also contain the Username, so that has to be taken in to account as well.

Is there a simple way to do this with maybe linq? Or am I actually going to have to write a whole filter function by myself here? And if so could you point me in the right direction of where to look to filter this easily?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Alright I just figured out that I'm sending a separate request for each filter, so it's like

```
external/api/user/firstname/{input}
external/api/user/lastname/{input}
external/api/user/username/{input}
```

Which means I can check after each request which one's are giving me data and then cross section them or something based on that. If I reach a full solution, I'll post it as an answer here.

Updated the original question to show everything a bit more clearly

Comment: You add the `exampleData` to `resultData`?

Comment: What syntax is `UserName: "ABC"`? That doesn't compile. Apart from that, it's not clear what you want. You want to find duplicates ignoring the order but at least two must match a given first-/lastname? `GetData` needs also two additional parameters for the user you want to find.

Comment: It's kinda scary to make it that intelligent. You should first determine if a request returns `FOO BAR` or `BAR FOO`. If you know what it returns, you can fill the appropriate fields

Comment: What will happen in case of  "FOO TEST"